# Python library for causal inference based on Judea Pearl's 'Book of Why'

Tags: python, causality, belief-propagation

Is there a widely-adopted implementation of the algorithms discussed in Judea Pearl's Book of Why? Topics include do-calculus, belief propagation, variable elimination, etc. Context would be defining a graphical model of some potentially causally related variables then quantifying the probability, direction and magnitude of such causal relationships.

Comment: I think this is one: https://github.com/py-why/dowhy

Comment: Microsoft has taken up the DoWhy library and morphed into PyWhy. https://github.com/py-why/py-why.github.io